# Create container in splunk phantom using phantom rest api

Tags: python, api, splunk

I want to create container in splunk phantom using phantom rest api. I am using splunk phantom community version. This is the body I am passing using python post method

```
payload={
            "description": "this is Useful description of this container.",
            "label":"events",
            "name":"xOkta event 110",
            "sensitivity": "red",
            "severity":"medium",
            "source_data_identifier": "4",
            "status": "new",
            "container_type": "default",
            "run_automation": "False",
            "due_time": "2020-06-10T19:29:23.759Z",
            }
```

and this is the code :

```
requests.post(url, auth=(username, password),json=payload, verify=False)
```

GET method is working. I am just unable to create container using phantom rest api(I am getting http status code 400 when post called). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's an aged question, but to help others, you never told what is the URL endpoint you are trying, but assuming it was right (/rest/container), then the 400 returned means that the endpoint rejected your payload for some reason, but when it does, it outputs the error message in a JSON response (message key).
I would suggest to enable debug mode OR to try the same call via cURL or Postman to validate.

So, in a nutshell:

Make sure you are using the right protocol (HTTP/HTTPS).
Make sure you are sending the POST to /rest/container endpoint with the payload in JSON format.
Make sure the payload has the label, which is mandatory, and it does exist.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).